# Function 'malloc' could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse, malloc

Every time I type malloc in eclipse it says it cannot be resolved. I have included `<stdlib.h>`

What is the problem? I have both GCC and Cygwin on my Windows 8.1 64 bit. malloc is not recognized by eclipse

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node{
         int data;
         struct node *next;
    };

    void insertbeg(struct node **href, int n){
         struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    }
```

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: Does Eclipse knows where to search for `stdlib.h` ?  OR Can you paste your code snippet here,If you are not getting include file not find error.

Comment: Paste your program and the error you are seeing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
Note that not responding to requests for clarification can lead to [downvoting](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) — corollary: don't ask a question when you can't pay attention for the next half hour.